# Rails: Make Devise helpers available in modules (generically outside a controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, helper

I'm developing using **Rails 4.1**.

I have the following module (in `app/policies/model_filters/helpers.rb`:

```
module ModelFilters
  module Helpers
    def allow(record, action)
    end
  end
end
```

I included it in my `app\controllers\application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ModelFilters::Helpers
```

And in the class where I want to use them (`app\bar\foo.rb`):

```
class Foo
  include ModelFilters::Helpers
```

The methods are included correctly but Devise helpers seems not to be available in the module described above; when I start my spec test I get:

```
undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #<Foo...
# ./app/policies/model_filters/helpers.rb:5:in `allow'
# ./app/bar/foo:13:in `recent'
```

Do you know how to make Devise helpers be seen in a module or, generically, outside a controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise helpers are only available within a controller because they only make sense within the context of an action being called.

If you think about your `Foo` class, what would `current_user` really mean? Within a controller, `current_user` is the user object that Devise can find from data stored in the `session`.

If you need to use a user object within a different class, it is best to pass the user to the class or method that you're calling.

Comment: Your answer is really good my friend. I was struggling with this concept and you're completely right. Devise stuff should be kept away from our modules.

Comment: Glad I could help out João!